# GraalVM 'nativeTest' not working on Windows 10

Tags: java, junit5, micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

The Gradle plugin for GraalVM provides the task `nativeTest` for running tests on a native image of the application. In my application, this works on MacOS but not on Windows 10 where the build is successful but the tests are skipped without error messages. Instead, the message

```
de.bugged.NativeTestTest > testItWorks() SKIPPED: Test is not bean. Either the test does not satisfy requirements defined by @Requires or annotation processing is not enabled. If the latter ensure annotation processing is enabled in your IDE.
```

is displayed.

A fresh Micronaut project with the feature `graalvm` enabled comes with a test `testItWorks` but `nativeTest` on Windows 10 skips the test without error message.